# filter(...).toArray is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying try to filter the results of a subscription. I get a List from the service class (job.service), and so I filter it, however filter returns an Iterable not List or Array. So I use toArray() but at runtime it throws an error saying "result.filter(...).toArray is not a function".

Could someone explain what is happening and give me a solution?

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from "@angular/http";
import { JobBase,JobMore, Employee, WorkCategory, TimeEntryApi } from "./models";
import { JobService } from "./job.service";
import { EmployeeService } from "./employee.service";
import { WorkCategoryService } from "./workcategories.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { List } from "immutable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
dummy: Array<JobMore> = [];
getJobs(): void {
    this.jobServ.GetJobs().subscribe(
        result => this.dummy = result.filter(x => x.status > 9).toArray(),
        error => console.error,
        () => console.log('completed function here or remove '));

    this.Submitted = this.dummy.length.toString();

}
```

job service

```
import { Component, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from "@angular/http";
import { JobBase, JobMore } from "./models";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { List } from "immutable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
@Injectable()
export class JobService {

    public jobs: List<JobMore>;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.GetJobs();
    }

    GetJobs(): Observable<List<JobMore>>{
        return this.http.get('./api/job')
            .map(this.JobsResponseMapper);

    }

    JobsResponseMapper(response: Response) {
        this.jobs = response.json();
        return this.jobs;
    }

}
```

Model

```
export class JobMore {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public jobName: string,
        public jobNumber: number,
        public status: number,
    ) { }
}
```

ETA:

I've now tried `result => Array.from(result.filter(x => x.status > 9))` I get the following error "Argument of type

> Iterable' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Iterable<{}>'. Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type
>   'Iterable'.

ETA2:

I have now tried this, with "this.dummy" inside the Array.from. this syntax doesn't make any sense to me though. `dummy` is the array and `Array.from`should be converting a list to an array and returning it. which should then be assigned to dummy. Wouldn't that make sense?

```
getJobs(): void {
    this.jobServ.GetJobs().subscribe(
        result => {
            Array.from(this.dummy = result.filter(x => x.status > 9)),
            error => console.error,
            () => console.log('jobs loaded: ' + this.jobs.length)
        });
}
```

I have also tired it this way. with the same error

```
getJobs(): void {
    this.jobServ.GetJobs().subscribe(
        result => {
            this.dummy = Array.from(result.filter(x => x.status > 9)),
            error => console.error,
            () => console.log('jobs loaded: ' + this.jobs.length)
        });
}
```

> Iterable' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Iterable<{}>'. Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type
>   'Iterable'.

job.service

```
GetJobs() {
    return this.http.get('./api/job')
        .map(this.JobsResponseMapper);

}
```

Comment: Did you try with `result => Array.from(result.filter(x => x.status > 9))` like you written above, or with the version I provided below in my answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure as to why you are assigning the incoming data as `List` in your Service if that is exactly NOT what you want?? Try and remove the `Observable` from your `GetJobs()`-method like so:

```
GetJobs() {
    return this.http.get('./api/job')
        .map(this.JobsResponseMapper);

}
```

But to as your question, try `Array.from` instead and a couple of brackets:

```
getJobs(): void {
    this.jobServ.GetJobs().subscribe(
        result => {
            Array.from(this.dummy = result.filter(x => x.status > 9)),
            error => console.error,
            () => console.log('completed function here or remove ')
            this.Submitted = this.dummy.length.toString();
        });
}
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't get a notification that you posted this answer. I'll to get back to do this this after noon. I some how broke my app playing around with Git, so I have to fix it it first.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've now tried "result => Array.from(result.filter(x => x.status > 9))" I get the following error "Argument of type 'Iterable<number, JobMore>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<{}>'. Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Iterable<number, JobMore>'. "

Comment: You have tested the wrong method, check that line again in my answer, you forgot the `this.dummy` in the line, and I also suggest you remove the Òbservable `List` in case that doesn't work.

Comment: I actually got it to work by changing everything to type array instead of type list but I still find this odd, and would like to find a solution to converting to an array.

Comment: Well, if you have put everything to Array, then it is an Array. That's why I suggested to remove the Observable<List> there. Why use it in the first place if you do not want a list? :) So is there still a problem?

Comment: To get my code to work no, to satisfy my curiosity yes.

The reason it was a list is because I was following a tutorial that used list.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Care to share the link (I assume it's online) for the tutorial, got a bit curious myself now :)

Comment: I would love to but I can't find it, I seemed to have not bookmarked it. it was just a general tutorial setting up a service with a list that was observable. if I come crossed it later I'll post back.